# data feching from dictonary inside an array and puting it into custom cell

Tags: ios, json, custom-view

i have an array like this

arr is the name of main array

```
{
[
name="";
place={"x1","x2"}
],
[
name="";
place={"y1","y2"}
]
}
```

i have to acess data from array which is in dictonary for key value "place" and to put it into the cell of table view  having label label1 and label2..

```
self.label1.text=[arr objectAtIndex:[indexPath.row]]valueforkey:@"name"]];
  self.label2.text=[[[arr objectAtIndex:[indexPath.row]]valueforkey:@"place" objectAtIndex[indexPath.row]];
```

will this works fine please tell me

thanks

Comment: It makes it easier to understand and debug if you breakup the compound statements into a series of statements with intermediate values. Readability will also improve if the new subscript syntax is used. (Actually not really new anymore).

Comment: i have main array .. i which dictonary are there having key values name & place . data stored in place is in form of array(say arr2) , and i have to acess that arr2 and print in label .. 

this example just came into my mind .. thnks

Comment: It will work, but probably not as you would want. For example, if you wanted to show y1 on the second label, you would have a problem since the indexPath of the second label is 1, not 0.

Answer (score 1):

Example of using the "Modern" subscripting syntax and intermediate values.

You should be able to replace this:

```
self.label1.text=[arr objectAtIndex:[indexPath.row]]valueforkey:@"name"]];
self.label2.text=[[[arr objectAtIndex:[indexPath.row]]valueforkey:@"place" objectAtIndex[indexPath.row]];
```

with the "Modern Syntax":

```
self.label1.text = arr[indexPath.row][@"name"];
self.label2.text = arr[indexPath.row][@"place"][indexPath.row];
```

or better yet:

```
NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
self.label1.text = arr[row][@"name"];
self.label2.text = arr[row][@"place"][row];
```

Comment: [ ] signifies an array, { } signifies a dictionary.

Comment: Syntax in the original question was wrong, in the first line there were two extra ]] on the right, the second one has no ] after the key in "valueforkey:@"place" objectAtIndex". Really tricky to get right when chaining like this, which you often want to. Using the "modern objective-C"  helps a lot by reducing the number of pairs of brackets. Only the array subscript (number) and dictionary key go in brackets.